# Some of my users are not getting the verification code

Tags: twilio, twilio-verify

I have an app that requirs users to verify their phone number. The app has mainly been used by people in Canada, until today. Now I'm getting a high number of reports from users in the USA that they are not receiving the verification code. I can see some users with area codes in the USA are receiving the code based on the fact my app shows their numbers are verified. However at least 2 of 3 new used with US area codes are showing as not verified.
What am I missing?

I haven't tried anything yet. I would love some guidence.

Comment: Why don't you open a ticket with twilio?

Comment: How are you delivering the verification codes? Do you use Twilio Verify or the messaging API? Ideally, you could add the source code to your question.